# I want to Scroll Down menu from a button in the screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to make a menu that scroll down from a button 
My Menu is a list view  the list view is inside a stacklayout so I show and appear using Change the Height request of the container stack layout Its working fine but I have a problem if want to start with Hiding the menu my problem is the stack layout always -1 that's mean the layout I think not totally binded

```
<StackLayout  
            x:Name="ParentListViewStackLayout"
            BackgroundColor="#242B3A" 
            Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Image x:Name="imgLogo"  Margin="0,60,0,15"
                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                       />
            <Image Source="{local:ImageResource BlankApp.Images.menu1.png} "
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="btnMenuClick"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <StackLayout 
                Spacing="0"
                x:Name="ListViewStackLayout">
                <ListView x:Name="MenuListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding 
MenuModals}" 
                          SeparatorColor="{StaticResource ControlTextColor}"
                          ItemSelected="MenuListView_OnItemSelected">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell >
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <controls:CustomStackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding MenuName}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource LableStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding MenuDescription}" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource LableStyle}"  />
                                        <Label Text="" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource LableStyle}" HeightRequest="25" />
                                    </controls:CustomStackLayout>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>


        </StackLayout>
```

The code Begind

```
public WashInternational()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
MenuListView.BindingContextChanged += MenuListViewOnBindingContextChanged;
        }

private void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            ShowMenue(false);
        }



        private void MenuListViewOnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            ShowMenue(false);
        }

public void ShowMenue(bool isShow)
        {
            if (isShow == _isMenuShow) return;
            var height = ListViewStackLayout.Height;
            if (_menuHeight <= 0)
            {
                _menuHeight = height;
            }

            _isMenuShow = isShow;
            if (isShow)
            {
                //MenuListView.TranslateTo(0, 0, 1000);
                ParentListViewStackLayout.HeightRequest = ParentListViewStackLayout.Height + _menuHeight;
                //ListViewStackLayout.ScaleTo(1, 500, Easing.Linear);
            }
            else
            {
                ParentListViewStackLayout.HeightRequest = ParentListViewStackLayout.Height - _menuHeight;
                //MenuListView.TranslateTo(0,- 500, 1000);
                //ListViewStackLayout.ScaleTo(0, 500, Easing.Linear);
            }


        }
```

The code is working fine but my problem in the initial state i can't start my application and the menue is hide because i don't know the right place to access the Height of my stack Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a method that can fetch the height at the beginning. I suggest if you dont't want to start you app with the menu , you should not the set the BindingContext at the beginning, but set it when you want to show the menu, e.g, a button click event

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
    list.Add(new Item { MenuName = "1", MenuDescription = "111" });
    list.Add(new Item { MenuName = "2", MenuDescription = "222" });
    list.Add(new Item { MenuName = "3", MenuDescription = "333" });
    BindingContext = new Model { List = list};
}
```

So the listView will be shown , and you can get the height of its contain stackLayout easily at that time.

Comment: I tried this solution but still the height of the stack layout -1